# Bad Index makes query very slow?

Tags: solr, lucene

So I have three Solr Servers. One is dedicated to indexing and two are dedicated as searchers. They have the master slave relationship.

There're about 70 millions documents, the size is roughly 70gb. And there're about 30 segments.

Here we have have something like contextual search where the user can put a long list of text, about 150 words as example, and he will get the documents which have something to do with the text he put in.

When I try it in a test server with the same spec (8 cores, 16gb), the result is quite fast (yes, I dropped hd cache and restarted Solr). First search takes about 2 secs, and the second search with another query take about 200ms.

The problem is when I tried it in production. The search took about 6 seconds with no really visible load on the memory or CPU (monitored using htop).

We tried so many things and we can't get the numbers down. Then we stopped the replication of a slave in production and copy the index over to the test server. And the test server is also slow (took like 26secs for the first, and about 6 seconds for the second one).

Does this means that the index is bad? Because in the test server we always use a fresh indexed index. Is there a way to keep the index in a good state without a fresh full reindexing?

//additional info - for the heap size, we reserved 6Gb for it, the rest are for OS/hd cache.
The things we have tried are optimizing the search method like trying out the pulsing posting format, the common terms query, better language detection and stopwords, etc.

Comment: There are several things you can do, but as you said `We tried so many things and we can't get the numbers down.` What did you try in detail? How big is the heap you assign to your solr? Did you try to [optimize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages?#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22) the index? How is your query? Are all queries slow?

Comment: We're trying to optimize now, but we are still waiting for more hd in our test server. But still, optimize is a very heavy stuff, iirc it actually creates a new index. I'm just wondering if there's any way to keep the index 'good'. It's slow only for the contextual queries (the one with ~150 words).

Comment: You can carry on shooting in the dark, but if you need a reliable answer, just hook a profiler and post the hotspots here or in the Lucene/Solr user forum.

Answer (score 1):

Can not give you a 100% working solution, but one that worked for me in the past was to do : `cat $SOLR/<collection>/solr/*/data/* > /dev/null`, that will help preload most of your data files into memory before solr gets to them.  I think the reason it is fast on your test server is that is where you indexed and OS memory is "aware" of your data files. Where as when you copy over files into a production Solr need to get them in a lazy load mode as queries arrive.

This may not be the case for you , give it a try. Another thing you can use is SolrMeter to check what is going on. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Sorry for not replying, but in the test server, we always drop the harddrive caches using `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` , but it's still fast. But you're right that it will get faster if the os is "aware" of the files.